# gRPC-python: switching Servicer while gRPC server is running ? (simulation - real mode switching)

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

For our new, open lab device automation standard (https://gitlab.com/SiLA2/sila_python) we would like to run the devices (=gRPC servers) in two modes: a simulation mode and a real mode (with the same set of remote calls, but in the first case it shall just return simulated responses in the second it should communicate with the hardware.

My first idea was to create two almost identical gRPC servicer python classes in separated modules, like in this example:

in **hello_sim.py**:

```
class SayHello(SayHello_pb2_grpc.SayHelloServicer):
  #... implementation of the simulation servicer
  def SayHello(self, request, context):
  # simulation code ...
  return SayHello_pb2.SayHello_response("simulation")
```

in **hello_real.py**:

```
class SayHello(SayHello_pb2_grpc.SayHelloServicer):
  #... implementation of the real servicer
  def SayHello(self, request, context):
  # real hardware code
  return SayHello_pb2.SayHello_response("real")
```

and then, after creating the gRPC server in server.py I could switch between simulation and real mode by re-registration of the servcier at the gRPC server like, e.g.:

**server.py**

```
# imports, init ...

grpc_server = GRPCServer(ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)) 

sh_sim = SayHello_sim.SayHello()
sh_real = SayHello_real.SayHello()

SayHello_pb2_grpc.add_SayHelloServicer_to_server(sh_sim, grpc_server)

grpc_server.run()

# ..... and later, still while the same grpc server is running, re-register, like

SayHello_pb2_grpc.add_SayHelloServicer_to_server(sh_real, grpc_server)
```

to be able to call the real hardware code;
or by exchanging the reference to the servicer object, like, e.g.:

```
# imports, init ...

grpc_server = GRPCServer(ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)) 

sh_sim = SayHello_sim.SayHello()
sh_real = SayHello_real.SayHello()

sh_current = sh_sim

SayHello_pb2_grpc.add_SayHelloServicer_to_server(sh_current , grpc_server)

grpc_server.run()

# ..... and then later, still while the same grpc server is running, re-register the real Servicer, like

sh_current = sh_real    
#  so that the server would just use the other servicer object for the next calls ...
```

but **both** strategies are not working :(

When calling the server in simulation mode from a gRPC client, I would expect that it should reply (according to the example): "simulation"

**gRPC_client.py**

```
# imports, init ....

response = self.SayHello_stub.SayHello()
print(response)
>'simulation'
```

and after switching to real-mode (by any mechanism) "real":

```
# after switching to real mode ...
response = self.SayHello_stub.SayHello()
print(response)
>'real'
```

What is the most clean and elegant solution to achieve this mode switching without completely shutting down the gRPC server (and by that loosing the connection to the client) ?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance !

PS:(Shutting down the gRPC server and re-registering would of course work, but this is not, what we want.)

Answer (score 0):

A kind colleague of mine provided me with a good suggestion:
One could use the dependency injection concept (s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), like:

```
class SayHello(pb2_grpc.SayHelloServicer):
    def inject_implementation(SayHelloImplmentation):
      self.implementation = SayHelloImplementation;

   def SayHello(self, request, context):
      return self.implementation.sayHello(request, context)
```

for a full example, see
https://gitlab.com/SiLA2/sila_python/tree/master/examples/simulation_real_mode_demo